# ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource unable to find message when default locale is "en"

Tags: java, spring, internationalization, locale, resourcebundle

Why is the spring "ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource" unable to find the proper message associated with a code when Locale.getDefault() returns **en**, but able to find the proper message when it returns **en_US**

**Default Locale: en_US**

```
key: CODE_1, Locale: Locale.US           = Hit
key: CODE_1, Locale: Locale.CANADA       = Hit
key: CODE_1, Locale: fr_CA               = Hit
key: CODE_1, Locale: null (use default)  = Hit
```

**Default Locale: en**

```
key: CODE_1, Locale: Locale.US               = Hit
key: CODE_1, Locale: Locale.CANADA           = CODE_1
key: CODE_1, Locale: fr_CA                   = CODE_1
key: CODE_1, Locale: null (use default)      = CODE_1
```

I have only one bundle that has the CODE_1 in the classpath which is **message_en_US.properties**

Comment: In which bundle/locale is "Hit" defined?

Comment: updated the post with the resource bundle where the Hit is defined

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The message is only defined for the `en_US` locale, since it's defined in the `message_en_US.properties` file. The reason that you get different behaviour when switching from locale  `en_US` (Locale.US) to `en` is that [ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource.html) by default does a [fallback](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource.html#setFallbackToSystemLocale(boolean)) to the system locale if a message is not found in the requested locale.

In the first case, when `en_US` is the default, then the message is always found, since the the requested local is `en_US` or when not, the message source does a fallback is to `en_US`, where the message is defined.

When the default locale is `en`, only the `en_US` query works, since that is looking in the correct properties file. For all others, the message is not found in the corresponding properties file, and it is also not found in the fallback locale `en`.

Answer (score 2):

It's because it cannot find less country/language-specific properties files `messages_en.properties` and `messages.properties`.

If you'd like to have a **default** bundle for all `en` languages regardless of the country, then you should have a `messages_en.properties`. If you'd like to have a **default** bundle for all languages, then you should have a `messages.properties`.

The `messages_en_US.properties` is in fact only useful whenever you have multiple English language dialects like `en_UK` and `en_US`, but then you should really also supply the another one for the other English "dialect". One of them should be named `messages_en.properties` which can then be used as "default" English bundle for visitors which are not specifying the country.